# Pivotal Tomcat Server Developer Edition v3.0-config is missing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am trying to run a sample program in spring tool suite. I am not able to run the Pivotal server and am getting the error message shown in the attached image.
Please can someone provide some suggestions to help.
Thanks in advance. [image: sts error]

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Tomcat and/or making sure everything is upgraded?

Answer (score 8):

After many weeks of frustration with this I think the answer is even easier than I thought.  My workaround was to keep installing a new server every time this happens.  Needless to say this clutters my workspace with many servers and wastes time.

Turns out that the darn server folder say Server7 or whatever server you are using in your STS  **MUST BE OPEN!!!**   This may seem obvious but as I open and close different projects I am working on I always click on "close unrelated projects".  Well this also closes the Server folder on my workspace!  I think the problem is just this simple.  Now to talk to the STS people to see if we can make the server intelligent enough to auto open the folder when we click start if it is not already open because I do appreciate being able to "close all unrelated projects" often.  Hope this saves some people some frustration.

Also double click your server in server view.  In the overview page make sure server configuration points to the directory of the server you are using.  In my example it would be Server9.  You will notice that if this Server folder is closed in package explorer it will not even be an option to choose.  This is when the light bulb went off for me why it could not find the server-config file.  See illustrated picture for guidance

.[image: STS tc-server config location illustrated]

ps. I finally found my Skitch for Linux alternative = Hotshots

UPDATE: to keep the server from closing when I click "close unrelated projects" simply right click the project and choose properties/project references then put a check mark next to the associated server of this project.  Then when you click "close unrelated projects" the server will remain open.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip!
That was really a idiotic message and I too had followed the original path of reinstalling the server

Answer (score 2):

This is due to that fact that server project might be closed. Please keep that open before performing deployment.

Answer (score 0):

delete the server and reinstall pivotal server or install tomcat 7.0 or tomcat 8.0. Tomcat is better option as the error logging better and less cache problem